# Remove double quotes from json object in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a Postgres function with an insert statement in which one of the columns has to be converted to json and inserted into the table. Here, I want to remove the double-quotes that enclose the json object.

Please help on how to achieve it.

```
REPLACE(json_build_array(adm_id),'"', '')
```

The above code errors out saying `replace(json, text, text) doesn't exist`. I tried to cast it to text and remove the double-quotes, but when I convert it back to json, it again adds double-quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [`trim`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-trim-function/) to remove the double quotes around the json document:

```
jsonb_build_array(trim('"' FROM adm_id))
```

or replace to remove them from every json element:

```
replace(jsonb_build_array(c)::text,'\"','')
```

Demo:

```
WITH j (c) AS (
  VALUES ('"{id: 1, txt: "foo"}"'),('{id: 2}')
) 
SELECT 
  jsonb_build_array(trim('"' FROM c)),
  replace(jsonb_build_array(c)::text,'"','')
FROM j;

     jsonb_build_array     |         replace         
---------------------------+-------------------------
 ["{id: 1, txt: \"foo\"}"] | [\{id: 1, txt: \foo\}\]
 ["{id: 2}"]               | [{id: 2}]
(2 rows)
```

Comment: @Manoharan I just updated my answer: `replace(jsonb_build_array(c)::text,E'\"',''),`

Comment: @Manoharan have you tried casting again to json? `replace(jsonb_build_array(c)::text,'\"','')::json`

Comment: Thanks !, it works as you have mentioned above after removing 'E'.  Please remove 'E' from the answer as well.

Comment: @Manoharan thanks! +1 for the quick feedbacks. Can you check it the answer now? Feel free to edit it as well.

Comment: @Manoharan awesome. Happy coding :)